# SNS does not send messages to SQS

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns, terraform-provider-aws

I have 2 SNS (order-finalized, customer-operations) and 2 SQS (notification-listen, customerPortal-listen) my team create these 4 resources via Terraform.

order-finalized(SNS) -> notification-listen(SQS) its crated 3 mounth ago and working fine.

customer-operations(SNS) -> customerPortal-listen(SQS) its crating now and messages do not publish to sqs.

SNS:

```
resource "aws_sns_topic" "order-finalized" {
  name              = "order-finalized"
  kms_master_key_id = "alias/aws/sns"
  tags = {
    Name        = "order-finalized",
    Environment = "dev"
  }
}

resource "aws_sns_topic" "customer-operations" {
  name              = "customer-operations"
  kms_master_key_id = "alias/aws/sns"
  tags = {
    Name        = "customer-operations",
    Environment = "dev"
  }
}
```

SQS:

```
resource "aws_sqs_queue" "notification-listen" {
  name                      = "notification-listen"
  delay_seconds             = 0
  max_message_size          = 2048
  message_retention_seconds = 86400
  receive_wait_time_seconds = 10
  redrive_policy = jsonencode({
    deadLetterTargetArn = aws_sqs_queue.deadletter.arn
    maxReceiveCount     = 1
  })

  tags = {
    Name        = "notification-listen"
    Environment = "dev"
  }
}

resource "aws_sqs_queue" "customerPortal-listen" {
  name                      = "customerPortal-listen"
  delay_seconds             = 0
  max_message_size          = 2048
  message_retention_seconds = 86400
  receive_wait_time_seconds = 10
  redrive_policy = jsonencode({
    deadLetterTargetArn = aws_sqs_queue.deadletter.arn
    maxReceiveCount     = 1
  })

  tags = {
    Name        = "customerPortal-listen"
    Environment = "dev"
  }
}
```

Subscriptions:

```
resource "aws_sns_topic_subscription" "order-finalized-target" {
  topic_arn = aws_sns_topic.order-finalized.arn
  protocol  = "sqs"
  endpoint  = aws_sqs_queue.notification-listen.arn
}


resource "aws_sns_topic_subscription" "customer-operations-target" {
  topic_arn = aws_sns_topic.customer-operations.arn
  protocol  = "sqs"
  endpoint  = aws_sqs_queue.customerPortal-listen.arn
}
```

Comment: You are not show us the queue policy which would allow receiving messages from the SNS topic. Do you have this policy?

Comment: @ErvinSzilagyi hi thanks for your comment. That's all I have in terraform. Am I need to add a policy in my terraform code? Or is it on my AWS accounts IAM menu?

Comment: You have to create a queue policy from Terraform. Example what should the policy contain is described in the aws docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/subscribe-sqs-queue-to-sns-topic.html (Step 2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @ErvinSzilagyi

I just add a policy and it solved my problem. I will post the terraform code for people who will search that think on google

```
resource "aws_sqs_queue_policy" "customerPortal-listen-policy" {
  queue_url = aws_sqs_queue.customerPortal-listen.id

  policy = <<POLICY
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "sqspolicy",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "First",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "sqs:SendMessage",
      "Resource": "${aws_sqs_queue.customerPortal-listen.arn}",
      "Condition": {
        "ArnEquals": {
          "aws:SourceArn": "${aws_sns_topic.customer-operations.arn}"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
POLICY
}
```